My Inline-Block Stopped Working As It Should
I have tried everything I could think of to place my figures properly into inline-block, but my pictures stack upon each other instead of laying next to each other, and now I'm wondering if it's me or the code.
This is my HTML:
<section class="figures" width="100%">
    <figure><img src="ios.jpg" width="175" height="247.5" alt="phone"><figcaption>Great Prices</figcaption></figure>
    <figure><img src="apple.jpg" width="175" height="247.5" alt="iphone"><figcaption>New Gadgets</figcaption></figure>
    <figure><img src="headphones.jpg" width="175" height="247.5" alt="headphones on a wall"><figcaption>Best Audio</figcaption></figure>
    </section>

This is my CSS:
 .figures{
        display: inline-block;
        transition: .2s;
        width: 100%;
        
    }
    
    .figures:hover{
        transform: scale(1.5);
    }
    
    .figures figcaption{
        font-weight: 100;
        font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    }
    
    .figures figcaption:hover{
      color: transparent;
    }

I tried aligning to centre, tried removing section block, tried replacing section block with a div, yet to no avail. I need my pictures next to each other, not stacked underneath each other like a list.
What could I be doing wrong?
